# Decoding a jpeg in Android

Tags: android, json, android-listview, jpeg

I have JSON data that I am viewing from a URL. There are many JSON objects in the JSON array, one of which is a jpeg image.

I would like to send that image to a listview in an Android app.

Right now I have the image JSON object linked to a private static final String TAG in my Java file. However, I realize that I must decode the image or I will receive an error of: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException and resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri.

I am in a long and ongoing search to understand how to decode the JSON jpeg image, much of such research taken place by viewing posts on this website so please do not mark as a duplicate question.

```
public class JSONBuilderActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //URL to get JSON
    private static String url = "";

    //JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CARS = "cars";      //root
    private static final String TAG_CARID = "CarID";
    private static final String TAG_CARVIN = "CarVIN";
    private static final String TAG_IMG= "CarMainImage";

    JSONArray carid = null;  //Initializes JSON array

    static String response = null;

    //Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>caridList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView lv = getListView();

        //Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //Gets values from selected ListItem
                String cars = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cars)).getText().toString();
                String car_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.car_id)).getText().toString();
                String car_vin = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.car_vin)).getText().toString();
                String model_img = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.model_img)).getTag().toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(JSONBuilderActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                //Sends data to MainActivity
                in.putExtra("TAG_CARS", cars);
                in.putExtra("TAG_CARID", car_id);
                in.putExtra("TAG_CarVin", car_vin);
                in.putExtra("TAG_IMG", model_img);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        //Calls async task to get json
        new GetCars().execute();
    }

    public class ServiceHandler {

        public final static int GET = 1;
        public final static int POST = 2;

        public ServiceHandler() {

        }

        /**
         * Makes service call
         * @url - url to make request
         * @method - http request method
         * */
        public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
            return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
        }

        /**
         * Makes service call
         * @url - url to make request
         * @method - http request method
         * @params - http request params
         * */
        public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) {
                    try {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

                    //Checks http request method type
                    if (method == POST) {
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                        //Adds post params
                    if (params != null) {
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                    }

                        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                } else if (method == GET) {

                    //Appends params to url
                    if (params != null) {
                        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                        url += "?" + paramString;
                    }
                        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                }

                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return response;

        }
    }

    /*
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetCars extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
           caridList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

            //Shows progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(JSONBuilderActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            //Creates service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            //Makes a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            //Prints the json response in the log
            Log.d("GetCars response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                    if (jsonStr != null) {
                        try {

                            Log.d("try", "in the try");

                            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                            Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");

                            //Gets JSON Array node
                            carid = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CARS);
                            Log.d("json array", "user point array");

                            int len = carid.length();
                            Log.d("len", "get array length");

                            for (int i = 0; i < carid.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = carid.getJSONObject(i);
                                String car_id = c.getString(TAG_CARID);
                                Log.d("car_id", car_id);

                                String car_vin = c.getString(TAG_CARVIN);
                                Log.d("car_vin", car_vin);


                                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.model_img, options);
                                int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
                                int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
                                String imageType = options.outMimeType;


                               // byte[] byteArray =  Base64.decode(jsonObj.getString(TAG_IMG), Base64.DEFAULT) ;
                                //Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

                                //String model_img = c.getString(TAG_IMG);
                                //Log.d("model_img", model_img);

                                //Hashmap for single match
                                HashMap<String, Object> matchGetCars = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                                //Adds each child node to HashMap key => value
                                matchGetCars.put(TAG_CARID, car_id);
                                matchGetCars.put(TAG_CARVIN, car_vin);
                                matchGetCars.put(TAG_IMG,  ); //idk
                                caridList.add(matchGetCars);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                    }

                   return null;
                }

        @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    //Dismisses the progress dialog
                    if (pDialog.isShowing())
                        pDialog.dismiss();

                    /**
                     * Updates parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(JSONBuilderActivity.this, caridList, R.layout.list_item,
                           new String[]{TAG_CARID, TAG_CARVIN, TAG_IMG}, new int[]{R.id.car_id, R.id.car_vin, R.id.model_img});
                   setListAdapter(adapter);
                    Log.v("List parsed", caridList.toString());
                }
    }
```

So any suggestions of how to decode a JSON jpeg image would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
}
```

Update:

```
 public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage){
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "CarMainImage", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

    public void saveBmpToFile(File filename, Bitmap bmp){
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
            // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    //------------------------
    public  boolean renameFileExtension(String source, String newExtension)
    {
        String target;
        String currentExtension = getFileExtension(source);

        if (currentExtension.equals(""))
        {
            target = source + "." + newExtension;
        }
        else
        {
            target = source.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("." +
                    currentExtension) + "$", Matcher.quoteReplacement("." + newExtension));

        }
        return new File(source).renameTo(new File(target));
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------
    public String getFileExtension(String f)
    {
        String ext = "";
        int i = f.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i > 0 &&  i < f.length() - 1)
        {
            ext = f.substring(i + 1);
        }
        return ext;
    }
    /*
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetCars extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            caridList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

            //Shows progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(JSONBuilderActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            //Creates service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            //Makes a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            //Prints the json response in the log
            Log.d("GetCars response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                    Log.d("try", "in the try");

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");

                    //Gets JSON Array node
                    carid = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CARS);
                    Log.d("json array", "user point array");

                    int len = carid.length();
                    Log.d("len", "get array length");

                    for (int i = 0; i < carid.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = carid.getJSONObject(i);
                        String car_id = c.getString(TAG_CARID);
                        Log.d("car_id", car_id);

                        String car_vin = c.getString(TAG_CARVIN);
                        Log.d("car_vin", car_vin);


                        String model_img=c.getString(TAG_IMG);
                        // byte[] byteArray =  Base64.decode(jsonObj.getString(TAG_IMG), Base64.DEFAULT) ;
                        //Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

                       // String model_img = c.getString(TAG_IMG);
                        //Log.d("model_img", model_img);

                        //Hashmap for single match
                        HashMap<String, Object> matchGetCars = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                        //Adds each child node to HashMap key => value
                        matchGetCars.put(TAG_CARID, car_id);
                        matchGetCars.put(TAG_CARVIN, car_vin);
                        matchGetCars.put(TAG_IMG, model_img);
                        caridList.add(matchGetCars);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }




        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Dismisses the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            /**
             * Updates parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(JSONBuilderActivity.this, caridList, R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[]{TAG_CARID, TAG_CARVIN, TAG_IMG}, new int[]{R.id.car_id, R.id.car_vin, R.id.model_img});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            Log.v("List parsed", caridList.toString());

        }

    }
```

Logcat:

```
V/List parsed﹕ [{CarMainImage=/images/image.php?w=200&i
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /images/image.php?w=200....
unable to resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: /images/image.php?w=200....
```

I do not understand why the parsed list is correctly logged and then those to error pop up. However, the JSON jpeg in the URL is not fully formatted like the jpeg in the log cat because the jpeg in JSON looks like: /images/image.php?w=200... and the jpeg in logcat looks like: /images/image.php?200.. So the difference is the ..can anyone elaborate if that could why the error messages are shown and/or offer suggestions to fix the errors?
I am very willing to research and go back and forth to understand anything that you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder  see , learn his "view holder" pattern to help with img tags   and with bitmaps in a list context

Comment: @RobertRowntree I will thoroughly look into this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
without thinking I will post you some conversion code:
**this is a place holder.**
required understanding:
Bitmap
Uri Provides an object representation of a "uniform resource identifier" 
URL (Universal resourse loacator) reference (an address) to a resource on the Internet.
file extensions. *.png *.jpg 

    this will be up-dated when my brain is not without sleep ;O)
more to come as I think , my brain hurts:

   //------------------------
                    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) 
                    {
                      ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                      inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                      String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
                      return Uri.parse(path);
                    }

                    public void saveBmpToFile(File filename, Bitmap bmp) 
                    {
                    FileOutputStream out = null;
                    try {
                        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
                        // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            if (out != null) {
                                out.close();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    }
    //------------------------
          public static boolean renameFileExtension(String source, String newExtension)
          {
            String target;
            String currentExtension = getFileExtension(source);

            if (currentExtension.equals(""))
            {
              target = source + "." + newExtension;
            }
            else 
            {
              target = source.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("." +
                  currentExtension) + "$", Matcher.quoteReplacement("." + newExtension));

            }
            return new File(source).renameTo(new File(target));
          }
        //---------------------------------------------------
          public static String getFileExtension(String f) 
          {
            String ext = "";
            int i = f.lastIndexOf('.');
            if (i > 0 &&  i < f.length() - 1) 
            {
              ext = f.substring(i + 1);
            }
            return ext;
          }
        //-----------------------
```

Comment: Hello. Yes, I remember you from another one of my posts. Thank you for responding to this one. I want to get a jpeg from JSON data stored at a URL and decode that image to be viewed in a ListView and NOT an ImageView in my Android application. Recently, I have been looking into Picasso for a getView method with no success so far. As I was before, I am still very willing to go back and forth discussing a solution.

Comment: Thanks! I edited your code slightly to fix a few issues that came about. I am looking into the difference between URL and URI, the use of .jpg and bitmap decoding now. I am also trying to now take the image uri and include the uri information in doInBackground to apply the uri to the TAG_IMG that corresponds that an image. Additionally, I am trying to take that image and view it in ListView and NOT ImageView. I look forward to hear from you.

Comment: bear with me I'm double busy, but I fully support the ethos of this site- to give something back. Over time build up a library of code you like and understand. Coding is a big commitment and rewarding. The points are just for fun (the addictive nature does not go unnoticed !). Your polite and enthusiastic, a good start for a programmer. keep it up. I hope many people help you build your skills and code base. Keep hacking !

Comment: Sometimes the journey is more important than the destination ;O)

Comment: Thank you for the tips (and compliments too)! It is inspirational to hear from a man who, based on your profile information and answers, is very educated and successful. I will definitely remember all the things you said. I could not agree more that the journey is sometimes (often to me) more important than the destination. Since you helped me the most, I will accept your answer without a question in my mind. Your help is always greatly appreciated. I built onto your code already and look forward continuing to do so for a long time. Thank you, Jon.

Comment: go to bountys and I'll set you a question, then if you answer it I'll give you 50 then I'm done with it

Answer (score 0):

Any of the [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) methods suit you?  There's a couple that can take a byte array and give you a `Bitmap`.  Then you can put your `Bitmap` into an `ImageView` fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks! I will continue to look into the BitmapFactory methods. However, you can please explain how I can put my Bitmap into a ListView rather than an ImageView?

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question to draw out what you'd expect it to look like.  If you want the image to be in every list item in your view, you'd best put an ImageView inside your list item layout file and populate it in your list adapter.  If you want it as the background, that should be a fairly straightforward call to set a View's background.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question to more thoroughly explain what I would like to do. Please take a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

As you just need to provide your image url and your imageView inside getView() function of your adapter. All work starting from download image from url to bitmap conversion and set to image view will be handle by Picasso.
For example : `Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(view/*Your image view*/);`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I am accessing JSON data through a URL so do I place that specific URL in the load () area? I am looking into Picasso now and how it applies to Android adapters and views. Can you please elaborate on the Picasso example that you provided? Thanks.

Comment: No, You just need to pass image url which you are getting inside JSON data. From your Json data get all image urls using for-each loop and save them into a List and then pass this List to your adapter.After follow this adapter code. https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso/SampleListDetailAdapter.java
Hope this will help you!!